# Why does my uberjar not work on Windows 7?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen

I created a new project using Clojure by doing this on a Mac:

```
lein new app clojure-noob
```

Created my uberjar using

```
lein uberjar
```

Sure enough, I can run this uberjar via:

```
java -jar target/uberjar/clojure-noob-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

And I get:

```
Hello, World!
```

Now I take this file to Windows 7 and give the same command:

```
java -jar clojure-noob-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

I seem to get an infinite wait. Why can’t I get to runt his .jar file on Windows?

The java version on Mac is:

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

The java version on Windows 7 is:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

lein version gives the following: `Leiningen 2.5.3 on Java 1.8.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Comment: lein version gives the following: `Leiningen 2.5.3 on Java 1.8.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Comment: Maybe you can get a hint when you run it as `java -verbose:class -jar ...` you should see at which class it will hang. Do you do some redirect of stdin/stdout in your code?

Comment: `lein new` creates a standard "hello world" app from a template. It does not do anything with stdin or stdout.

Comment: Thanks SubOptimal for your suggestion! That showed me that various classes were being loaded. That gave me patience to wait on and finally and after a long sequences of class loads, it printed "Hello, World!" which was the expected output. I had just created a "Hello World" template project only - the default project created by "lein new app". I do not understand why my machine is so slow - perhaps because I am running a VirtualBox VM - but I had written just a hello world project in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was trying to run the .jar from shared folders on a Windows 7 VM from VirtualBox running on a Mac. This IO is very slow.

When I just copy that file to, say, Desktop and run from there - the access is quiet fast. Thanks SubOptimal for helping me figure this out.